# How to make length of values and index equal when applying a function to a multiindex dataframe?

Tags: pandas, function, apply, multi-index

Suppose I create a multiindex dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

date_index = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2019', end='1/3/2019')
symbol_index = ['AAPL','BOA','GE','MSFT']
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([date_index, symbol_index], names=['Date', 'Symbol'])
col = ['val_to_change','new_val']
data = pd.DataFrame(index=idx,columns=col)
```

I want to make some calculations row by row like this:

```
initial_variable = 0

def calc(row):
    global initial_variable
    row['val_to_change'] = initial_variable
    #I make further calculations here with row['val_to_change']
    row['new_val'] = row['val_to_change'] + 500
    initial_variable = row['new_val'].values
    return row

data = data.groupby('Date').apply(calc)
```

This gives me the desired output:

```
                   val_to_change  new_val
Date       Symbol                        
2019-01-01 AAPL                0      500
           BOA                 0      500
           GE                  0      500
           MSFT                0      500
2019-01-02 AAPL              500     1000
           BOA               500     1000
           GE                500     1000
           MSFT              500     1000
2019-01-03 AAPL             1000     1500
           BOA              1000     1500
           GE               1000     1500
           MSFT             1000     1500
```

However, if the dataframe does not have the same amount of `Symbol` level index for each `Date` index, then I get an error for the above function. If I drop a `Symbol` from a `Date`:

```
data.drop(('2019-01-01','AAPL'),inplace=True)
```

And now apply the same function to `data`, then I get an error:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

because the first `Date` index has now only 3 `Symbol` indices.  How can I overcome this problem? I want to apply a function like this on my dataframe, which has a multiindex but the multiindex does not have the same amount of `Symbol` index for every `Date` index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and parameter `dropna=False` for avoid drop new missing rows filled by `NaN`s:

```
data.drop(('2019-01-01','AAPL'),inplace=True)

data = data.unstack().stack(dropna=False)
data = data.groupby('Date').apply(calc)
print (data)
                   val_to_change  new_val
Date       Symbol                        
2019-01-01 AAPL                0      500
           BOA                 0      500
           GE                  0      500
           MSFT                0      500
2019-01-02 AAPL              500     1000
           BOA               500     1000
           GE                500     1000
           MSFT              500     1000
2019-01-03 AAPL             1000     1500
           BOA              1000     1500
           GE               1000     1500
           MSFT             1000     1500
```